# Prevent "Sleep / Stand by" in iBooks

Tags: ipad, books

Does anyone know how to prevent the iPad from going to sleep / stand by when in the iBooks app?

I'm using the iPad as a music stand with my charts, but while I'm playing the song, the screen goes black... this (as I'm sure you can imagine) totally blows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to prevent sleep *only* in the iBooks app, but if you find yourself in a situation where you don't want your iPad to go to sleep, go into Settings -> General -> Auto-Lock and select "Never". With this option selected, the iPad won't go to sleep without user input.

Comment: +1 Thanks. This is what I've done... I just know there are other apps that can override this setting just while your in that app.